# Windows Server 2016 Standard - Downgrade rights for Server 2008 VM converted from physical machine

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, licensing

*Greetings, first question asked here; if there's anything amiss, let me know and I'll get it straightened out.*

I am in a circumstance that leads me to consider the following possibility, should it be in compliance with Microsoft's licensing schemes:

I am considering the possibility of migrating a Windows Server 2008 Standard (not R2) machine (hardware failing), to a Hyper-V VM on a Windows Server 2016 Standard.

The 2K8 instance is rented in a datacenter, so we do not own the license for it.

**My understanding is as follows:**

Server 2016 Standard allows for the use of no less than one Hyper-V instance of the same, under the same license, on the same machine.

Server 2016 Standard provides downgrade rights to Server 2008 Standard R2 or earlier.

**My question can be summarized as follows:**

Would it be possible to re-activate the installation of Server 2008 Standard (not R2) within a Hyper-V instance on Windows Server 2016 Standard, and activate it under the premise of a license downgrade, and if so, could this possibly cause issues for the datacenter's existing license?

Comment: Are you 100% Windows Server 2016 has downgrade rights to Windows Server 2008 which isn't currently supported? No; **You cannot activate Windows Server 2016 with a license to Windows Server 2008 license**

Comment: Microsoft's current downgrade rights brief (March 2017) still lists "2008 R2 or earlier" as valid downgrade options for Server 2016 standard. It's in extended support until some time in 2020 (mainstream dropped in 2015), same as 2008 R2. Microsoft seems to be a little less eager to kill their outdated server OSes. --- Also, the question was about re-activating an existing Server 2008 instance.

Comment: Alright;  But my second statement is still true.

Comment: Second statement is absolutely true :) At any rate, thanks for the input.